# New Connection fails during Add New Data Source Dialog

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, exception, configuration

### The Problem

If I have Visual Studio 2010, Service Pack 1 installed, and I go to Data, Add New Data Source and click Database, it brings up the standard Choose Your Data Connection wizard page.

On that page, if I have an existing connection configured, I can then select it, and add that data source to my project, no problems, no issues.

On the other hand, if I click New Connection... it just bombs out, wizard closes, as if I had done nothing. Now keep in mind, Visual Studio doesn't close, and there are no exceptions, errors, or warnings, the dialog window just disappears.

### Unsuccessful Attempts to Resolve Issue

I've checked the simple things, using a debugger, and a valid machine config file, not sure what else I might be missing.

1. **Using a Debugger**

   I tried starting a 2nd copy of Visual Studio as I did this, and
   attaching a debugger to the process, with all exceptions checked in
   my debug menu, and still nothing.
2. **Validating machine.config file is valid**

   I backed up my machine.config file, and used another person's working machine's machine.config file, and I'm still having issues.

   I have since reverted back to my own machine.config file.

   I suspect the machine.config might be the issue, but I thought
   taking a working one should work, unless I'm missing one of the
   registered providers? I don't know enough about how this wizard
   works behind the scenes though, or what sections/lines of the
   machine.config file exactly drive the wizard.
3. **Uninstalling all third-party database providers**

   I have recently tried uninstalling Oracle, SQLite, beta versions of SQL Server Compact Edition, and MySQL providers in hopes that one of them set a registry entry or configuration entry that was negatively impacting my ability to create new connections and the error still occurs.
4. **Reinstalling Visual Studio**

   I reinstalled Visual Studio, complete uninstall, and reinstall, no extensions, or nothing, and the issue exists, definitely convinced its a configuration error at this point, I could use the expert opinion of someone who knows more about the configuration behind the scenes for this dialog though.

Any help in resolving the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of SQLite are you using?  The release prior to the current had design time support, but they've removed it in the latest release.  If you installed the designer support for the SQLite ADO .NET Provider maybe it's bugging out with VS2010?

Comment: Currently it's uninstalled, but I was using 1.0.74. I have not reinstalled it yet at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue. Delete all records in event viewwr and works.

Start -> run

Type "eventvwr"

Select application

Select "Action" > "Clear All Events" from menu

Save or not as you wish the events backup. Do the same with "System"

Answer (score 6):

Visual studio 2012 solution.

Close visual studio.

Open the event viewer, go to Application Log, and find *Errors* with source `devenv`.

Mine said

```
The following information was included with the event: 

.NET Framework Data Provider for MySQL: An unexpected error occurred in the data provider.
```

Then i opened registry editor and went to:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\DataProviders\`

And deleted the key that reffered to the faulty data provider

`{c6882346-e592-4da5-80ba-d2eadcda0359}`

(default) = .NET Framework Data Provider for MySQL

Comment: Well, dang, the registry entry for my data provider was actually wrong, so that could have been the case. In my case it actually was a SQLite entry under VS 2010's registry entries for DataProviders, and lo and behold, SQLite never showed up in my list before, and now it does, kudos!

Comment: This was actually a solution for me, fault MySQL provider as well thanks OP

Answer (score 2):

1. Try using Server Explorer window  to add your Connection.
2. Try defining your Connection String from Settings.settings file
3. Try moving/deleting all the *.datasource files from the project/solution before adding the connection
4. Try creating a new, empty solution and see if the problem is solution-indepentent
5. Try finding out what registry keys and files Visual Studio uses when the issue occurs with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) from Sysinternals

Comment: Thanks, while it didn't fix the problem directly, step 1, using server explorer flung an exception (about Oracle ODP.NET) that was useful in helping me further track down the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue today.

Solved it by removing a tag in machine.config file:

```
**32-bit**
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[version]\config\machine.config

**64-bit**
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\[version]\config\machine.config 

Tag to remove:
<DbProviderFactories/>
```

Comment: I installed a third .net data adapter that filled this section in and when I deleted this section it started to work.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*The problem is that when the dataset is modified, the dataset is linked to the bi object.* **I solved the problem like this:** I made a change and registered the dataset and it **came up an error**. I then undo it with `CTRL + Z`, **the error is resolved**. Then I moved forward with `CTRL + Y`, **and the error went away**. Thanks to this solution, I added the query, added a new table.