# Visual Studio 2013 crashes when building connection string to microsoft sql server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, database-connection

I am trying to migrate my application from mysql to microsoft sql server 2014.  When I create a new application and attempt to build a connection string to a microsoft sql server 2014, I can test the connection and it returns an successful connection but vs2013 crashes when I click the OK button.  This process works on the mysql connection I have  on another application so I suspect it is looking at a bad reference to the sql-server dll.  I have looked everywhere and there is no reference to this problem.

This is exactly the same problem as this post 
[Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Stopped Working when adding connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846750/microsoft-visual-studio-2013-stopped-working-when-adding-connection)  but user, B413, never post a fix to his problem

Comment: Can you provide us with the connection string, and munge as little as possible? Also, did you try with the server name as well as trying with the server IP?

Comment: I tried to create a separate connection string by duplicating the string that was created when I made the new database...didn't work.  I tried changing the servername to localhost...no luck.  I didn't try the ip because localhost works on the Mysql side of things.  I also tried removing and replacing the namespace references for the sql server.  I tried about everything until I stumbled upon the fix.  I bet a dollar to a donut, the problem is in the xml file but I don't know enough about the file to try to find the fix.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for this problem.  It's not pretty but it works.

1. Go to Server Explorer and right click on data connections
2. Select "Create a new SQL database"
3. Click the down arrow for the server name and select your sql server
4. Give your database a name like "test"

This will create a new database in the sql server

5. Now go and right click on the new instance of your new database in server explorer and chose "Modify Connection"
6. Now click the "advanced" button
7. Now scroll down to the Source section and change the name of "Initial Catalog" to the database you wish to connect to.
8. Ok out of everything and you should be able to see your tables.
9. Go the Sql Server and delete the instance of the new database you created for this exercise.

Good Luck...I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to (temporarely) remove the MySQL DataProvider entry in the registry [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16239171/2366136). Hope it helps others!